# How to automatically select other row of same ID when user selected a row in GridView ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with checkboxes for the user to select. I would like other rows with the same ID to be automatically selected when the user selects a row, because it must be selected in pair.

I have tried iterating through all the rows and added the selected ID in a list, and iterate the rows again to select rows with ID exist in the list, but I realised this is not an efficient way to do it.

Does anyone have any experience having similar issue or can someone suggest a way to do this more efficiently, and if possible through client-side javascript to reduce the traffic going back and forth.

Really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

```js
function Check_Click(objRef) {
  //Get the Row based on checkbox
  var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (objRef.checked) {
    //If checked change color
    row.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  } else {
    //If not checked change back to original color
    if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
      //Alternating Row Color
      row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f0f1";
    } else {
      row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }

  //Get the reference of GridView
  var GridView = row.parentNode;

  //Get all input elements in Gridview
  var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    //The First element is the Header Checkbox
    var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];
    //Based on all or none checkboxes
    //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
    var checked = true;
    if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
      if (!inputList[i].checked) {
        checked = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  headerCheckBox.checked = checked;
}

function checkAll(objRef) {
  var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
    var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
    if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
      if (objRef.checked) {
        //If the header checkbox is checked, check all checkboxes and highlight all rows
        row.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        inputList[i].checked = true;
      } else {
        //If the header checkbox is checked, uncheck all checkboxes and change rowcolor back to original
        if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
          //Alternating Row Color
          row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f0f1";
        } else {
          row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        inputList[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;">
  <tr class="TblHeaderStyle">
    <th scope="col">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl01_checkAllGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl01$checkAllGvLedger" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
    </th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_DTL_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_NAME</th>
    <th scope="col">ST_MV</th>
    <th scope="col">RB_MV</th>
    <th scope="col">MVMT</th>
    <th scope="col">AMT</th>
    <th scope="col">TX_DATE</th>
    <th scope="col">STATUS</th>
    <th scope="col">CD_BY</th>
    <th scope="col">CD_TIME</th>
    <th scope="col">RKS</th>
    <th scope="col">STATUS_MAN</th>
    <th scope="col">REFER_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">BATCH_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">FD_CODE</th>
    <th scope="col">SW_TYPE</th>
    <th scope="col">ST_MV_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">RB_MV_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">AMT_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">EXCHG_RATE</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_AMT</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_UNIT</th>
    <th scope="col">N_UNIT</th>
    <th scope="col">N_DATE</th>
    <th scope="col">FD_PER</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">TL_SW_DONE</th>
    <th scope="col">TT_TL_SW</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl02_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl02$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0000001</td>
    <td>MR ABC</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>from</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>853.97</td>
    <td>0.5855</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblAlternateRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl03_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl03$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0000001</td>
    <td>MR ABC</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>994.43</td>
    <td>0.5028</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>00007762</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblAlternateRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl03_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl03$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>0000002</td>
    <td>MR DEF</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>994.43</td>
    <td>0.5028</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>00007763</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnGenerate" value="Proceed >" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to process selected transactions?&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnGenerateSwitching&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
  id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_btnGenerate" class="ButtonStyle" />
```

Comment: When posting markup it helps to see what the rendered output markup is instead of the code that generates the markup as that is the part your JavaScript will run against.

Comment: I've added code snippet. But it doesn't render any output. Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: The server-Side code that generates the markup is not going to work. You need to put the actual client-side rendered HTML from your page into the question and Snippet as that is what the JavaScript interacts with. We need to see that to be able to help you better with your JavaScript. If your client-side HTML is huge, just copy only a few rows into the question to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I've edited the code snippet can run now. Could you please take a look and help me? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is many ways to do this but you could get all the rows each time you click a row and then iterate through them using a `for` loop, ignoring the header row.

Within the loop you only process all rows which hqave the `holder id` of the **selected Row**.

Set the checked state of all rows not equal to the selected row to be the same as the selected row.

You then can move your highlighting code inside the loop to apply it too all relevant rows.

```js
function Check_Click(objRef) {
  //Get the Row based on checkbox
  var selectedRow = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
  var selectedId = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;

  // Get All Rows
  var allRows = selectedRow.parentNode.parentNode.rows;

  for (i = 1; i < allRows.length; i++) {
    var row = allRows[i];
    var id = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    var chkBox = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    
    if (id == selectedId) {
      if (row != selectedRow) {
        chkBox.checked = objRef.checked;
      }

      if (chkBox.checked) {
        //If checked change color
        row.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      } else {
        //If not checked change back to original color
        if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
          //Alternating Row Color
          row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f0f1";
        } else {
          row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //Get the reference of GridView
  var GridView = selectedRow.parentNode;

  //Get all input elements in Gridview
  var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    //The First element is the Header Checkbox
    var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];
    //Based on all or none checkboxes
    //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
    var checked = true;
    if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
      if (!inputList[i].checked) {
        checked = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  headerCheckBox.checked = checked;
}

function checkAll(objRef) {
  var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
    var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
    if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
      if (objRef.checked) {
        //If the header checkbox is checked, check all checkboxes and highlight all rows
        row.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        inputList[i].checked = true;
      } else {
        //If the header checkbox is checked, uncheck all checkboxes and change rowcolor back to original
        if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
          //Alternating Row Color
          row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f0f1";
        } else {
          row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        inputList[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;">
  <tr class="TblHeaderStyle">
    <th scope="col">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl01_checkAllGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl01$checkAllGvLedger" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
    </th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_DTL_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">HOLDER_NAME</th>
    <th scope="col">ST_MV</th>
    <th scope="col">RB_MV</th>
    <th scope="col">MVMT</th>
    <th scope="col">AMT</th>
    <th scope="col">TX_DATE</th>
    <th scope="col">STATUS</th>
    <th scope="col">CD_BY</th>
    <th scope="col">CD_TIME</th>
    <th scope="col">RKS</th>
    <th scope="col">STATUS_MAN</th>
    <th scope="col">REFER_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">BATCH_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">FD_CODE</th>
    <th scope="col">SW_TYPE</th>
    <th scope="col">ST_MV_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">RB_MV_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">AMT_DTL</th>
    <th scope="col">EXCHG_RATE</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_AMT</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_UNIT</th>
    <th scope="col">N_UNIT</th>
    <th scope="col">N_DATE</th>
    <th scope="col">FD_PER</th>
    <th scope="col">TRANS_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">TL_SW_DONE</th>
    <th scope="col">TT_TL_SW</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl02_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl02$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0000001</td>
    <td>MR ABC</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>from</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>853.97</td>
    <td>0.5855</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblAlternateRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl03_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl03$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0000001</td>
    <td>MR ABC</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>994.43</td>
    <td>0.5028</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>00007762</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TblAlternateRowStyle">
    <td align="center">
      <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_gvLedger_ctl03_chkThisGvLedger" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$gvLedger$ctl03$chkThisGvLedger" onclick="Check_Click(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>0000002</td>
    <td>MR DEF</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>10/7/2014</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>CV 201709</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>CVA_2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>994.43</td>
    <td>0.5028</td>
    <td>10/07/2014</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>00007763</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnGenerate" value="Proceed >" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to process selected transactions?&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnGenerateSwitching&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
  id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_btnGenerate" class="ButtonStyle" />
```

Comment: It worked! It's perfect and exactly what I need. God bless you. You have really made my day. Thank you so much.

Comment: Another option would be to give each row an attribute containing the holder id, similar to `data-holder-id="2"` then you could do a straight up `document.querySelectorAll("[data-holder-id=' + selectedId + ']")` off course instead of `document.` you can use the table for selection scope instead. That would help, in case you have tons of rows, to only process the ones matching to begin with.